# SyntaxError: Expected corresponding JSX closing tag for <input>

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native, webpack

I really sorry, for most of you its like a stupid question... but my brain doesn't work right now. So this is my index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './style.scss';

const MyComponent = () => (
    <div style="margin:auto;">

        <table cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0" style="margin:0 auto;margin-bottom:2rem;">
            <tr>
                <td><span
                    style="  height: 100px;width: 100px;background-color: darkgrey;border-radius: 50%;display: inline-block;"></span>
                </td>
                <td style="color:#2c4e88;">
                    <h1><p>swedavia</p></h1>
                    <h2><p>swedish airports</p></h2>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>


        <form>
            <div style="color:darkgrey;padding: 16px;">
                <label htmlFor="uname">Username</label>
                <input type="text" name="uname" required>
                    <label htmlFor="psw">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="psw" required>
                        <div style="margin-top:2rem;">
                            <button type="submit">?????????</button>
                            <span style="float: right;padding-top: 16px;"><a href="#">Forgot password?</a></span>
                        </div>
            </div>
        </form>

    </div>
);
export default MyComponent;
```

this is index.html

```
<html> 
  <head>
    <title>My Component Demo</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"> 
  </head> 
  <body> 
    <noscript>
      You need to enable JavaScript to run this app. 
    </noscript> 
    <div id="root"></div> 
  </body> 
</html>
```

and this is examples/src/index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { render} from 'react-dom';
import MyComponent from '../../src';
const App = () => (
    <MyComponent />
);
render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

i don't understand how can i render it
it doesn't work when i want to render full form...
but when it is for example

```
<h1>Hello</h1>
```

then it works...

Comment: `import MyComponent from '../../src';` this is path of the index file you are rendering component.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal SyntaxError: Expected corresponding JSX closing tag for <input>

Comment: @BhojendraNepal you're right, I blindly assumed there was `{` but I see it's `(`, sorry

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti It happens always, coz it's JSX. I have also faced many times with the syntax before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have error with input elements:

```
<input type="password" name="psw" required>
```

Replace all input elements like this:

```
<input type="password" name="psw" required />
// ---------- self closing tag ------------^
```

---

In normal html you can code the input elements without self closing tag because the browsers handle them while rendering. But JSX doesn't understand the element which has no closing tag.

Be careful with other [replaced elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Replaced_element) as well. Whenever, you need to use them, you need to have closing tag.